# How can I tell SELinux to give vsftpd write access in a specific directory?

Tags: permissions, ftp, selinux, vsftpd

I've set up vsftpd on my Fedora 12 server, and I'd like to have the following configuration. Each user should have access to:

- his home directory (/home/USER);
- the web directory I created for him (/web/USER).

To achieve this, I first configured vsftpd to chroot each user to his home directory. Then, I created `/web/USER` with the correct permissions, and used `mount --bind /web/USER /home/USER/Web` so that the user may have access to `/web/USER` through `/home/USER/Web`.

I also turned on the SELinux boolean `ftp_home_dir` so that vsftpd is allowed to write in users' home directories.

This works very well, except that when a user tries to upload or rename a file in `/home/USER/Web`, SELinux forbids it because the change must also be done to `/web/USER`, and SELinux doesn't give vsftpd permission to write anything to that directory.

I know that I could solve the problem by turning on the SELinux boolean `allow_ftpd_full_access`, or `ftpd_disable_trans`. I also tried to use audit2allow to generate a policy, but what it does is generate a policy that gives ftpd write access to directories of type `public_content_t`; this is equivalent to turning on `allow_ftpd_full_access`, if I understood it correctly.

I'd like to know if it's possible to configure SELinux to allow FTP write access to the specific directory `/web/USER` and its contents, instead of disabling SELinux's FTP controls entirely.

Answer (score 4):

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/myftp/pub(/.*)?"
```

Be sure to include the `(/.*)?` at the end of the directory name.

---

> I also tried to use audit2allow to generate a policy, but what it does is generate a policy that gives ftpd write access to directories of type public_content_t; this is equivalent to turning on allow_ftpd_full_access, if I understood it correctly

Essentially, yes; since SELinux allows directories/files labeled with `public_content_t` to be shared between different services.  However, further access control is in place through the use of `sebooleans` (or `sebool`, more precisely).

Giving "ftpd full access", doesn't mean giving it the rights to do/read/write what and where it wants.  SELinux has designated policies in place for the services on your system; meaning, `ftpd` is allowed to read files if the directory's file context (`fcontext`) is `public_content_t`.  SELinux gives write permissions to the ftp server if the directory's fcontext is `public_content_rw_t`; other services such as samba, apache, etc. have to be allowed write permissions to those directories through the booleans, according to the pertaining [RedHat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-File_Transfer_Protocol-Configuration_Examples.html).  If your "local policy" gives ftpd write access in directories labelled `public_content_t`, it essentially strips away a layer of security.  Therefore, I suggest labeling the directory with the `public_content_rw_t` context, and removing your custom generated local policy.

For further information and details, please see the [SELinux wiki pages](http://selinuxproject.org/page/FTPRecipes).

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to just `chcon` the directory to the right context?

Comment: chcon is for temporary changes, `semanage` is persistent; also, there's a difference between the two in that `chcon` changes the file on the FS, while `semanage` updates the policy itself with the new info, as mentioned in [this mailing list entry](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.devel/154131)

Comment: I'm afraid this information not precise, at the least. The fact that `chcon` works on the filesystem also means it is permanent, not temporary, and lasts until the context is changed again (e.g. by `chcon` or by `restorecon`). On the other hand, `semanage` IMO just updates the database and doesn't change the file context which would render this answer *incomplete*. According to the mailing list, you have to use `semanage` *and* `restorecon` as a replacement for `chcon`, not *only* `semanage`.

Comment: right...since SELinux is guided by the database, any changes to SELinux's policy would render the `chcon` incompatible.  DAC is used *before* SELinux to check for rwx permissions, after which SELinux's MAC policy decides whether the process is allowed access within the scope/context of the FS directories/files.

Comment: Take a look at [SELinux's Wiki page](http://selinuxproject.org/page/FTPRecipes) for further explanation and details.

Comment: Well the kernel selinux module doesn't use the path database at all. And you seem to ignore my last comment where I warned you that modifying the database doesn't result in modified file context. You seem to assume that the path database is part of the in-kernel selinux policy which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
```

> If SELinux is to blame, there's a few SELinux booleans worth looking at.
>
> Best start is: getsebool -a | grep ftp
>
> You'll see something like
>
> allow_ftpd_anon_write --> off
>   allow_ftpd_full_access --> on
>   allow_ftpd_use_cifs --> off
>   allow_ftpd_use_nfs --> off
>   ftp_home_dir --> on
>   ftpd_connect_db --> off
>   httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
>   tftp_anon_write --> off
>
> Not all of these are relevant to vsftpd, for example the >httpd_enable_ftp_server is for Apache running FTP, and tftp_anon_write is for >tftpd. I'd start with:
>
> setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
>   setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on

Source:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8129

Answer (score 0):

Let's summarize the known information into a better answer. You have already stated a solution using particular selinux booleans or allowing write access to any directories with `public_content_t` which are both suboptimal for you.

What you need is to *ensure* that the directories have proper selinux context. You have paths /home/$USER/Web and /web/$USER, the former used for mounting the latter via `--bind` option.

The first idea that comes to my mind is to try it without the `mount --bind`. I guess that would work for FTP access for your first testing and maybe you already tried that. You need to check whether those files are now accessible via HTTP. If not, it means your Apache Userdir doesn't work and should be fixed before playing with `mount --bind`. You probably want to have those directories in /web because of external storage, right?

I guess the only problem here is that the /web/$USER directory isn't configured in the same way as would work automatically for /home/$USER/Web. You can create another directory like /home/$USER/Test and compare the results of `ls -lZ` on them. You would clearly see the difference.

You can use `chcon` to change the context and then check what happens. It's a low level tool and it's not a systematic solution but it helps you test things quickly. You can also do a little bit of black magic here and just run `restorecon` on the /home/$USER/Web and I believe it will set the context correctly.

The final solution would be to use `semanage fcontext` to alter the path database to use the correct context also to /web as well as any /web/$USER and *especially* to have the context of /home/$USER/Web *the same* as for /web/$USER as the `mount --bind` is a bit of black magic itself.

After altering the path database, don't forget to run `restorecon -r /web` on and it might be good to also test that `restorecone -r /home` doesn't break that. Also check whether new /web/$USER directories are created with the right context or `restorecon` is required. If you're not happy with the situation, you can configure `restorecond` to monitor those directories and fix the context immediately but that should be a last resort.

Always remember that selinux itself doesn't know the path database but works solely with the security contexts of the respective files.

I don't have a selinux-enabled distribution at hand right now, otherwise I would give you more command line examples and the solution would be more precise. I can fix it up later with a centos/fedora virtual if necessary. Now I see that the question is rather old. I was tricked by the insufficient answer, but I hope it will still help someone.